# Azure DevOps: Run task only if previous task ran

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want the `PublishTestResults@2` task to run ONLY if the previous task `script` (which runs unit tests) actually ran.

- If I use `condition: succeededOrFailed()` then `PublishTestResults@2` runs even if the previous step did not run - I thought this was what `condition: always()` was for.

1. How does one make a task contingent on the previous task even if the previous task failed?
2. What is the difference between `always()` and `succeededOrFailed()`?

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```yaml
    # This step only runs if the previous step was successful - OK
    - script: |
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/application/src
        yarn test:unit --silent --ci --reporters=jest-junit
      displayName: 'Jest Unit Tests'
      env:
        JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_DIR: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults
        JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME: 'jest-junit.xml'

    # This step ALWAYS runs - NO
    #  This step should ONLY run if the previous step RAN (success OR fail)
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Frontend Test results'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: JUnit
        searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults
        testResultsFiles: 'jest-junit.xml'
        testRunTitle: 'Frontend Test Results'
        mergeTestResults: false
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

UPDATE: I suspect the Publish step "Frontend Test results" is running because the 2 previous steps were NOT run but the one before that was successful:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`succeededOrFailed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#succeededorfailed) for a setp is equivalent to `in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed')` and this is why your `Frontend Test results` ran.

If you want to publish only when `Jest Unit Tests` was executed you may use logging commands to set variable and then use this variable in condition:

```yaml
 # This step only runs if the previous step was successful - OK
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes" #set variable doThing to Yes
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/application/src
        yarn test:unit --silent --ci --reporters=jest-junit
      displayName: 'Jest Unit Tests'
      name: JestUnitTests
      env:
        JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_DIR: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults
        JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME: 'jest-junit.xml'

    # This step ALWAYS runs - NO
    #  This step should ONLY run if the previous step RAN (success OR fail)
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Frontend Test results'
      condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), eq(variables['JestUnitTests.doThing'], 'Yes'))
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: JUnit
        searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults
        testResultsFiles: 'jest-junit.xml'
        testRunTitle: 'Frontend Test Results'
        mergeTestResults: false
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

Comment: OK, so is there no difference between always() and succeededOrFailed()?

Comment: @Marc, `always()` will run even if the run is cancelled while `succeededOrFailed()` will run either the pipeline failed or not, but if it is cancelled.