# Azure Devops - how do i run the successor test only if the successor test passes?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I tried to find answers, but so far I have not been able to....

Setup:  I have defined a list of test cases in Azure DevOps.  I have defined Successor/Predecessor relationships for several of the test cases.  The idea is that the Successor test should not be executed if the Predecessor test has failed

Example:

1. Test 1 (Predecessor)
2. Test 2 (Successor)
3. Test 3
4. Test 4 ... and so on.

Question: How do I define the dependency in Successor test 2 to look at the outcome of Predecessor test 1?

Comment: In the meantime, you can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64863159/azure-devops-run-task-only-if-previous-task-ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "defined Successor/Predecessor relationships for several of the test cases", do you mean adding a link as shown in the figure below to each test case?
[image]

If you run these test cases manually, there is currently no such a feature. You can submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to request more control over the execution order.

If you run automatically, you can put different tests in different test tasks. If the previous step fails, subsequent steps will not be executed, which is the default if there isn't a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) set in the YAML.

Comment: I want to be able to add the link to the Successor as part of test steps - for easy navigation.  Since my test cases will be run manually, I will request the feature as you suggested.  THANKS :)